# Get only newer Records from MySQL Table, filtered by date attributes

Tags: mysql

I would like to filter out old records and present only newer ones. The idea is currentDate minus 2 years. One record looks like this (table Symposium):

Attributes:

```
ID;Day;Month;Year;Firstname;Lastname;Symposium_title;Speakers;
```

Records

```
1;26;10;2012;Markus;Meier;Topic MySQL;5;
3;26;10;2011;Markus;Meier;Topic PHP;5;
6;26;01;2010;Markus;Meier;Topic CSS;5;
```

Wished output

```
1;26;10;2012;Markus;Meier;Topic MySQL;5;
3;26;10;2011;Markus;Meier;Topic PHP;5;
```

I could easily do a small php to filter out older data, but I'm sure there is a way to do it direct with mysql in one command.

some query like this (this is just pseudo code)

```
SELECT * FROM Symposium WHERE (current_data() - 2 Years);
```

remark: The attributes day;month;year will not be changed. There are more then 50 tables, that are build up by this attributes.  So don't recommend change of the table.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: @jade: he does not need all the other data. The question was not about ordering, but filtering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [STR_TO_DATE function](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date) and [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) for this task:

syntax:

```
STR_TO_DATE(string, format)
```

So in your code:

```
SELECT * from Symposium
WHERE DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(concat(Day,'-',Month,'-',Year),'%d-%m-%Y'), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) > NOW();
```

(sadly, I don't have a MySQL at hand right now, so I can't test it, but unless there is some very basic typo in it, it should work)